# Failed to execute, How to enter terminal before login

Tags: x11, configuration, system-recovery

I've modified my `~/.xinitrc` and now the X11 startup fails. I just see a message on the screen saying something like *Failed to execute*.

I don't have a recovery option in my grub, so I cannot boot into a terminal session. How can I open a terminal and repair my `.xinitrc`?

Comment: Switch to another TTY...

Comment: `.xinitrc` is not used during boot, only during login. Is the problem during boot or during login? To help you diagnose the specific problem we would need to know more than “something like” the last few words.

Comment: You don't need to have a recovery option in your grub, you can just edit the command line to add it this once.

Comment: It seems I've mistaken, The problem is during login. And if I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 it just logins back I think as part of auto login.

Comment: Try a TTY other than the one where X should be running.

Comment: Could you elaborate for someone that is new in this community?

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-F2` or `3`, `4`, `5`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to a different virtual console, e.g. by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>; most distributions provide a terminal login on virtual console 2.

If there is no such login, then use any installation live CD/DVD/USB, mount the home partition, and edit your `.xinitrc` from there.

Comment: OP is trying to run X on TTY1, so *any* other TTY would work...

Comment: I've tried, I think I have some auto login that prevents me to do so. I'll download the live CD, Is it a regular download ?

Comment: Sure, almost any installation media will do, for most of them allow you to enter a virtual console or even provide an xterm or similar.